# Hashtable sorting using bubble sort c++

Tags: c++, sorting, hashtable, key-value, bubble-sort

I have a problem with sorting my Hashtable. I have methods to compare numbers, letters and bubble sort algorithm. The sorting output is not my desired one because it prints the hashtable by insert-order (first inserted - first printed) and what i want is sorting by the key in ascending order or by the value is ascending as well. Keys are Integers and values are Strings.
Here's the code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>

using namespace std;
const int size = 100;

class Binding
{
    public:
        int key;
        string value;
        Binding *next;

        Binding(int key, string value)
        {
            this->key = key;
            this->value = value;
            this->next = NULL;
        }
};

class HashTable
{
    private:
        Binding** tarray;

    public:
        HashTable()
        {
            array = new Binding*[size];
            for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
            {                
                array[i] = NULL;
            }
        }

        int insert(int key, string value)           
        {
            int hash = (key % size);
            Binding *record = array[hash];
            Binding *previous = NULL;

            if(record != NULL)
            {
                previous = record;
                record = record->next;
            }
            else if(record == NULL)
            {
                record = new Binding(key, value);

                if (previous == NULL)
                {
                    array[hash] = record;
                }
                else
                {
                    previous->next = record;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                record->value = value;
            }
        }

        int compareLetters(const void *a, const void *b)
        {
             Binding *A = (Binding*)a;
             Binding* B = (Binding*)b;
             int compare = strcmp(A->letter, B->letter);

             if(compare == 0)
                  return 0;
             else if(compare > 0)
                 return 1;
             else if(compare < 0)
                 return -1;
        }

        int compareNumbers(const void *a, const void *b)
        {
            Binding *A = (Binding*)a;
            Binding *B = (Binding*)b;
            if(A->key > B->key)
                return 1;
            else if(A->key < B->key)
                return -1;
            else 
                return 0;
        }

        void bubble_sort()
        {
            Binding *temp;
            for(int i=1; i<size; i++)
            {
                for(int j=0; j<size - i; j++)
                {
                    if(compareNumbers(&array[j], &array[j+1]) == 1)
                    {
                        temp = array[j];
                        array[j] = array[j+1];
                        array[j+1] = temp;
                    }
                }   
            }
        }
```

Comment: `if(record != NULL)` `{...}` `else if(record == NULL)` `{...}` `else` is simply exhaustive and wrong construction.

Comment: Please don't delete a question and re-post it; edit your question to add extra detail if necessary.

Comment: `int compareNumbers(const void *a, const void *b)`   Stop using `void *`.  Use the actual types (`Binding *`).

Comment: I changed that but it doesn't work either..

Comment: I am not sure that I understand what you're trying to do. If you sort the hash table, the hash will no longer work. Are you sure that this is what you need?

Comment: The thing is I want to sort the key-value that i have already inserted into hash table. F.e if i inserted 5 pairs , i would like to sort them and print in ascending(key) order :)

Comment: @MyStaa A hash table, like the one in your code, is sorted by the hash value, which is computed from key. If you change the order, you will no longer be able to access the table by key. What you need is std::map, which is based on a sorted tree. If you cannot use a map, just copy your data in a vector, sort it and print it.

Comment: @ZDF , could you give me a tip or show how can i copy the data to vector?

Comment: @MyStaa Assuming that your insert method works (I did not check it), you will have to add an `at( key_type)` method to retrieve a value by key. You will also have to know how many elements are  in your table (keep track of count in `insert`). Allocate a vector of `key_type` (that's why you need the count) copy the key values into this vector and sort it. Then, use the `at` method to retrieve the values using the keys in vector. To traverse the table, traverse each list in `tarray`. [Alternatively, you could use a vector of Binding and thus avoid the use of `at`]

Comment: Thank you for the tips @ZDF, i already had at(int key) method implemented but i thought It was irrelevant, so I didn't pasted It in here. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

You take the addresses of `Binding` pointers and pass them `compareNumbers` function in this line:

```
                if(compareNumbers(&array[j], &array[j+1]) == 1)
```

That is wrong because `compareNumbers` function excepts values convertible to `Binding *` as arguments, not `Binding **` as you pass them now.

Comment: And you don't need to declare the parameters to `compareNumbers` as `void *`; if you used the proper types and dropped the useless casts the compiler would have told you the problem.